# Set parent for programmatically created menu links

Tags: 8, entities, navigation

I'm currently programmatically generating a menu and menu links inside it. This is working but I'm having trouble setting the parents for the links. Here is my current code

```
    $langcode = 'es';
    if (empty($menu_id)) {return ['#markup' => 'menu not specified'];}
    $menu = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu')
        ->create([
            'langcode' => $langcode,
            'status' => TRUE,
            'label' => $menu_id,
            'id' => $menu_id,
            'description' => 'this menu was created programmatically',
        ])->save();

    $items = [
        '1' => 'item 1',
        '2' => 'item 2',
        '3' => 'item 3',
    ];
    $parent = NULL;
    foreach ($items as $id => $title) {
        if ($id == '2') {$parent = '1';} else { $parent == NULL;}
        $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
            'title' => $title,
            'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nid],
            'menu_name' => $menu_id,
            'expanded' => true,
            'langcode' => $langcode,
            'status' => TRUE,
            'parent' => $parent,
        ]);

        $menu_link->save();
        var_dump($menu_link->getParentId());
    }
```

This line

```
var_dump($menu_link->getParentId());
```

is actually displaying the correct parent. But when visiting the menu in the admin page the parent is not set and is at the top level of the menu. Is there a specific issue with my code? How would you set the parent of a programmatically generated menu link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out when setting the parent you don't use the id of the menu_link_content you use the 'menu_link_content:' followed by the uuid of the link. Here's an example of a properly formatted parent field.

> 'menu_link_content:0025c274-4db3-4745-b51e-714c998b5a50'

I fixed the code like so

```
    foreach ($items as $id => $title) {
        if ($id == '2') {
            $parent = 'menu_link_content:' . $previous_menu_link->uuid();
        } else {
            $parent == NULL;
        }

        $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
            'title' => $title,
            'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nid],
            'menu_name' => $menu_id,
            'expanded' => true,
            'langcode' => $langcode,
            'status' => TRUE,
            'parent' => $parent,
        ]);

        $menu_link->save();
        $previous_menu_link = $menu_link;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I was building some ridiculously complex setup to create a hierarchical menu... then realized I could do it as you're doing, with an array of menu items, just by setting a value like `'top_level' => TRUE` and keying on that to flag when there's a top level item to store it's UUID and use it for the children in a loop.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @AlxVallejo I don't think this case is specifically documented but you can see the MenuLinkContent class here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Entity%21MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/8.8.x and the method being used is create which you can see here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3Acreate/8.8.x

Comment: OK, but if you want to add a new sub-item in an existing menu which you don't happen to create at the same time, what is the simplest or the recommended way of getting the parent's uuid from any other information? (e.g. the parent's "title" or its position/"coordinate" in the tree [e.g. second child of first item, or so])?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using.

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('menu')
  ->create([
    'id' => 'test-menu',
    'label' => 'Test menu',
    'description' => 'Description text.',
  ])
  ->save();

$menu_link_1 = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Link 1',
  'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/foo'],
  'menu_name' => 'test-menu',
  'expanded' => TRUE,
]);
$menu_link_1->save();

$menu_link_2 = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Link 2',
  'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/bar'],
  'menu_name' => 'test-menu',
  'expanded' => TRUE,
  'parent' => $menu_link_1->getPluginId(),
]);
$menu_link_2->save();
```